# Running Minecraft server through NGINX - Only ports 80 and 443 available

Tags: nginx, minecraft

I've been looking at possible ways to run a Minecraft server behind a reverse proxy on NGINX with a IP/location/to/server (e.g. 127.0.0.1/minecraft-server) connection, but the only information that I've found is to either use a SRV DNS record, or to use a stream proxy (but no further information is included about this possibility, or it does not provide a NGINX location config).

I need to use a NGINX reverse proxy as ports 80 and 443 will be the only ports that will be open externally via our provider (HTTP/S servers only allowed, they can't be used for anything else and the connection will be managed by administrators), and I don't have a domain. I can get one and a SSL certificate if that's all that's needed in order to be able to do this.

I know Minecraft runs on a TCP or UDP connection, and that's part of the reason why this is not an easy task, but since this is the only way I can possibly have future external access to my Minecraft Server (self hosted), I need a way to run the connection through an HTTP reverse proxy.

Is there any way to do this through NGINX or NGINX+other software?

Thank you in advance.